# AngularJSFilter not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am very new to Angular JS. Just started an hour back to dig into it.

I cannot get the filter API to work on this page. I am drawing a blank ..

I am very sorry to ask such a silly question...

jsfiddle.net/khirthane/52hN5/

Comment: model not modal
updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eu9WE/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html data-ng-app="">

<body data-ng-init="customers=[{name:'John Smith', city:'phoenix'},{name:'John gh', city:'phodafghfenix'},{name:'John gjkgukj', city:'jhjhoenix'}]">


    Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>


    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{ cust.name }}  -  {{ cust.city }}</li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just had a typo.

```
data-ng-modal="name"
```

should be

```
data-ng-model="name"
```